# AWS EC2 sudo apt update not woking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to update an EC2 instance, using sudo apt update. The instance has been updated previously with no issues.

Security Group attached to the EC2 allows all outbound traffic.
The EC2 is in a public subnet with an internet gateway.
I can ssh into the instance and ping 8.8.8.8.

Today running

```
sudo apt update
```

Returns this error

```
Err:2 http://ca-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
  Could not connect to source.ca.lan:3142 (172.31.14.73). - connect (113: No route to host)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you changed DNS and/or configurations in `/etc/apt`?  It's unclear why you're trying to connect to an invalid top level domain.

Comment: @stdunbar  I just checked, in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptproxy, I found Acquire::http { Proxy "http://source.ca.lan:3142"; },  I'll have to check with my colleague if/why these files have been modified.

Comment: @stdunbar I removed that entry, now it works, thanks for pointing me in the right direction